# CSS selectors priority

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have following HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>One</li>
  <li class="two">Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

and following CSS:

```
.menu > li {
  color: red;
}

.two {
  color: green;
}
```

but all list items have red color. And if I change it to this:

```
ul > li {
  color: red;
}

.two {
  color: green;
}
```

secong list item with `.two` class have now green color as I wanna. Is this any bug or why it work this way?

http://codepen.io/Chovanec/pen/iJsuC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [calculate the specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) of those selectors (here's a [friendlier version](http://specificity.keegan.st/)):

- `.menu > li` has specificity `0,0,1,1` (**11**).
- `ul > li` has specificity `0,0,0,2` (**2**).
- `.two` has specificity `0,0,1,0` (**10**).

The bold numbers are just the base-10 representations of the specificities. You won't always be able to write them that way, as `0,0,100,0` is also a valid specificity and must be represented in a base higher than 100.

So back to your question: `.menu > li` > `.two` > `ul > li`, as class selectors are more specific than tag name (type) selectors.

Comment: @michal chovanec you could also use .menu li:nth-child(2){color: green;} or .menu li:nth-child(even)